# Maven more than 1 settings.xml

Tags: maven

I have more  than 1 settings.xml file and I want to specify the 1 I want to use when I run `> mvn` from the command line, because running `mvn help:effective-settings` is showing 1 file but it seems that is using the other one

Comment: Possible duplicate of [maven command line how to point to a specific settings.xml for a single command?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25277866/maven-command-line-how-to-point-to-a-specific-settings-xml-for-a-single-command)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
mvn --settings settingsYouWant.xml clean install
```

If you add the argument -X to your maven command (debug) you can see which one is picking.